# Easeljs: pause an eventListener

Tags: events, easeljs

Here is my code:

```
function main(){
/*.. stuff */
  ball.on("tick",collision);
  player1.on("pressmove",player1mov);
  field.addChild(player1);
  field.addChild(player2);
  field.addChild(ball);
  field.update();
}
function collision(){
    var a=player1.x-ball.x;
    var b=player1.y-ball.y;
    d=Math.sqrt((b*b)+(a*a));
    if(Math.round(d)<=50 ){
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML="Collisione";
        vel();
        urto();   
    }

}
```

I can't figure out how to pause the event: 'ball.on("tick",collision)' and resume it after the urto() function to avoid the maximum call stack limit error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pause the event listener firing, but you can pause the Ticker, and then check that property, or the `paused` property of the tick event.

From [the Ticker documentation](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html#property_paused):

```
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
 createjs.Ticker.paused = true;
 function handleTick(event) {
     console.log(event.paused,
       createjs.Ticker.getTime(false),
       createjs.Ticker.getTime(true));
 }
```